# stripe firebase functions to set default payment

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, stripe-payments, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to set the last card added to the stripe as the default via firebase functions though I can't seem to get it to work.

```
// Add a payment source (card) for a user by writing a stripe payment source token to Realtime database
exports.addPaymentSource = functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}/sources/{pushId}/token').onWrite(event => {
  const source = event.data.val();
  if (source === null) return null;
  return admin.database().ref(`/users/${event.params.userId}/customer_id`).once('value').then(snapshot => {
    return snapshot.val();
  }).then(customer => {
    return stripe.customers.createSource(customer, {source});
    return stripe.customers.update(customer, {default_source: source});
  }).then(response => {
      return event.data.adminRef.parent.set(response);
    }, error => {
      return event.data.adminRef.parent.child('error').set(userFacingMessage(error)).then(() => {
        // return reportError(error, {user: event.params.userId});
        consolg.log(error, {user: event.params.userId});
      });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to return two things in this one function. That isn't going to work. It should create the source, but it won't update it.

```
return stripe.customers.createSource(customer, {source});
return stripe.customers.update(customer, {default_source: source});
```

Comment: yes it creates and doesnt update, I need the update the default card as it critical the correct card is charged

Comment: You can't return two functions. So you need to create the source, then add an additional callback after creating the source that will then update the default source. I'd have to dig into their docs but the idea would be. createSource().then(=> update()).then(=> update your database). You try to create and update at the same time (and you try to return both functions). So just bump the second into its own callback function and you'll be good to go.

Comment: This is correct. Only the first return statement will be used to propagate the promise, the second one will never even be evaluated. @Paul'Whippet'McGuane please consider using an analysis tool such as jslint or eslint too catch these kinds of shenanigans statically.